# Customize the fields that Redmine calendar displays

Tags: calendar, redmine, redmine-plugins

I'm interested in using Redmine for a scheduling/rental system and I'm running into a particular issue with the calendar that's slightly annoying.

On the calendar, I'd like the ability to choose the fields that appear in the default view but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.  I'd ideally like to have the Subject be the main link instead of the tracker and issue id.

Any way to modify which fields Redmine displays on the calendar?

Answer (score 0):

Easyredmine has a customizable calendar plugin which can show calendar events by the name you have choosen. I'm not sure if it has options to show already created issues with your preferable field as title.

http://www.easyredmine.com/online-store/easy-redmine-plugins/meeting-manager